# dpkg: error processing package pick-colour-picker (--install) in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, dependencies

When I am installing color-picker in Ubuntu 16.04 from the terminal this error occurs.
I use this command to install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i pick-colour-picker_1.5-0~201606011144~ubuntu14.04.1_all.deb

(Reading database ... 263715 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack pick-colour-picker_1.5-0~201606011144~ubuntu14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking pick-colour-picker (1.5-0~201606011144~ubuntu14.04.1) over (1.5-0~201606011144~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pick-colour-picker:
 pick-colour-picker depends on python-pkg-resources; however:
  Package python-pkg-resources is not installed.
 pick-colour-picker depends on python-gi-cairo; however:
  Package python-gi-cairo is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package pick-colour-picker (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pick-colour-picker
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems that you haven't installed all the dependencies.
Try running this command:

```
sudo apt -f install
```

It should solve your problem. If it doesn't work, try:

```
sudo apt install python-pkg-resources python-gi-cairo
```

Those two packages are the missing dependencies of color-picker in your case.

Comment: i have already python but what is this python-gi-cairo? can you please tell me

Comment: This link will help you understand https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python/python-gi-cairo

Answer (score 0):

Your package is not being installed due to some unmet dependencies. I would like to suggest to install gdebi and install your .deb package from it. It will automatically install required dependency packages.

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Once installed, Right click on your .deb file and open it with gdebi. Cheers :)

Comment: thanks but i don't want to install gdebi. i know it . have you another way?

Answer (score 0):

@Arman

in that case do the following:

First move your deb file to /var/cache/apt/archives/ directory. 
Then run following command:

`sudo apt-get install package_name`

After executing this command, it will automatically download its dependencies.

**If you still want to stick with dpkg dear, then:**

You can install it using 
`sudo dpkg -i debfile` 
followed by

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

I hope both options will meet your need :)